# custom php library with pear local installation

Tags: php, pear

Hello i wish to be able to deploy a PHP web application along with a local installation of PEAR.

To be more specific, i am trying to find a way to do a 'per-application' or local installation of PEAR if this is possible.

For example:

The application 'MyApplication' is located in: /var/www/applications/myapplication

The php library is located in: /var/www/applications/myapplication/library

I am looking for a way to do a per-application installation of PEAR since not all applications are managed by me (and i want to control which PEAR packages are installed and when).

I found some tutorials for a local PEAR installation (on a shared host) but i don't know if my scenario fits the one for a local PEAR installation.

Any thoughts/help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use this approach for our deployments.

For each deployed app, we create externals/pear directory via:

```
pear config-create /path/to/app/externals /path/to/app/conf/.pearrc
```

Then we reset the include path for PHP to *only* have the /path/to/app/externals/pear/php directory.

We have been using this approach for a couple of years with great success.

Comment: Thanks. But how do you manage package installations in each deployed app?

Comment: once you've created the local pear, you can mange it via:

pear -c /path/to/app/conf/.pearrc [normal pear command]